# reorder column in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

How do I reorder the LandUse column in this dataframe:

```
Region                       North         South
LandUse          Year                           
Corn             2005  149102.3744  2078875.0976
                 2010  201977.2160  2303998.5024
Developed        2005    1248.4416    10225.5552
                 2010     707.4816     7619.8528
Forests/Wetlands 2005   26511.4304    69629.8624
                 2010   23433.7600    48124.4288
Open Lands       2005  232290.1056   271714.9568
                 2010   45845.8112   131696.3200
Other Ag         2005  125527.1808   638010.4192
                 2010  257439.8848   635332.9024
Soybeans         2005   50799.1232  1791342.1568
                 2010   66271.2064  1811186.4512
```

Currently, 'LandUse' is organized alphabetically. I want it to be in following order:

```
lst = ['Open Lands','Forests/Wetlands','Developed','Corn','Soybeans','Other Ag']
```

Comment: does it work if you `reindex`: `df.reindex(index = lst)`?

Comment: hmm, it is not working, could it be because when I print  df.index, I get: Index([u'Open Lands', u'Forests/Wetlands', u'Developed', u'Corn', u'Soybeans', u'Wheat', u'Other Ag'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `df = df.loc[lst]` to reorder the index.

Comment: as per above, it is not working, could it be because when I print df.index, I get: Index([u'Open Lands', u'Forests/Wetlands', u'Developed', u'Corn', u'Soybeans', u'Wheat', u'Other Ag'], dtype='object')